# How to hide a div on one click and unhide it on another click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am wanting to add an else statement to my javascript, currently if a user clicks a link then a div hides, but i want it so that if they click the link again the div unhides. can someone please show me how i might do this thanks?

```
<a id="myLink" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:myLinkButtonClick();"><h3 id="bobcontent1-title" class="handcursor"><img src="assets/img/help_support/howdo.png" width="302" height="45" /></a>

<script>
function myLinkButtonClick()
{
    $(".nswp-frame2").hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: HTML belongs in html files, CSS belongs in css files, JS belongs in js files. Don't mix and match.

Answer (score 6):

Since it seems you're using jQuery, you could simply use the `toggle()` method.

For example:

```
$('#myLink').on('click', function() {
    $(".nswp-frame2").toggle();
});
```

The `toggle()` method shows and hides the element interchangeably, depending if the element is currently visible or hidden.

As a side note, mind how this example binds a handler to the `click` event with the `on()` method in an unobtrusive manner, instead of the obtrusive (inline) code in your example. This also means that this snippet should be part of a separate script declaration and preferably executed after page load. So a more complete example would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myLink').on('click', function() {
            $(".nswp-frame2").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function myLinkButtonClick()
{
    var $element = $('.nswp-frame2');
    if($element.is(':visible')){
        $element.hide();
    } else {
        $element.show();
    }
}
```

Or, you could also simply use the .toggle method:

```
function myLinkButtonClick()
{
    $('.nswp-frame2').toggle();
}
```